# Email 5 months before contract End date

Tags: workflow, formula-field, email-alert

I want to create an email to send to our team whenever a contract is about to expire. it needs to be 5 months before it expires. i cant set  a formula inside of the field becasue you can't send an email based on that. Is there anything in salesforce I can use to get that working ? I was thinking about a workflow but I never did one and I'm not sure where to start.

[image]

Wouldn't that only work exactly 151 days before the contract end date ? Or is it within that time scale ?

Comment: Write a Time Trigger Workflow. It would be easy. Try it!

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005245

Comment: @Greg Time-Dependent Workflow will solve your problem. It has before and after options add no of days and select before option.

Comment: great So how would I start going about that ? Workflows & Approvals > Workflow Rules or flows ? I can't seem to find the  Add Workflow Action in the Immediate Workflow Actions section

Comment: what criteria are you selecting ? please select **created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria** under **Evaluation Criteria** and under **Rule Criteria** select **formula evaluates to true** write true in the formula, then you will get an option to add **Time-Dependent Workflow**

Comment: Could you have a look at my edit ?